# #include <nanopb/pb.h> Could not build module 'nanopb'

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, cocoapods

I know this has been answered previously on Stack however, the reason for this was outdated cocoapods (not being at least version 1.2.0)

I am currently running version 1.9.3 and using Xcode 12 and still getting this error.

I have done the usual steps to see if the following will solve the issue;

1. Cleaned Build Folder
2. Removed derived data
3. Restarted Xcode
4. Updated Cocoapods
5. Checked Cocoapods is on latest version

I believe this is a module pulled in along with Firebase/Firestore

pods used:-

- pod 'Firebase/Auth'
- pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
- pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
- pod 'FirebaseFirestoreSwift'
- pod'Firebase/Database'
- pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`pod update` or keep using Xcode older version which you have no error